# Python: comparing two sets and writing results to a third set

Tags: python, csv, set

So this is what I have, I think what I'm looking for is pretty straight-forward.  I want to be able to take the items in set c2 that are not in c1 and add those to c3.  Sets c1 and c2 populate correctly.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

```
import csv
import sys
c1 = set()
c2 = set()
c3 = set()

with open(new, 'r') as newfile:
    newreader = csv.reader(newfile, delimiter=('|'))
    for row in newreader:
        c1.add(row[0])

with open(new, 'r') as oldfile:
    oldreader = csv.reader(oldfile, delimiter=('|'))
    for row in oldreader:
        c2.add(row[0])

for item in c2:
    if item not in c1:
        c3.add(item)

print(c1)
print(c2)
print(c3)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
c3 = c2 - c1
```

its that easy.

Or even:

```
c3 |= c2 - c1
```

if c3 already has some content.

See:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Comment: I've tried that, maybe its something with the syntax, I'm using 3.4.  It prints the full sets of c1 and c2 but for c3 displays "set()".

Comment: Found my problem, I was referencing the same csv file and trying to find the differences between the sets.

Answer (score 1):

You can either do a direct subtraction, such as `c3 = c2 - c1`, or you can use the `difference()` function, i.e. `c3 = c2.difference(c1)`. Both of them are pretty readable and I think they end up doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `set.difference()` method:

```
c3 = c2.difference(c1)
```

which can also be written as

```
c3 = c2 - c1
```

Check out all of the `set` methods [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set).